# 2 Person Same Number Verification

Tags: logical-deduction, cryptography, algorithm

Alice and Beth both receive a random integer from 1 through 10, inclusive. They only know the number that they are given.

The two of them want to come up with an algorithm to check that their sampled numbers are indeed different, but ensure that they reveal no information about their individual numbers (apart from the fact that they are different!).

Either find an algorithm that does such, or prove that no such algorithm exists.

Comment: is there unlimited guesses? is this supposed to be efficient? can I simply make them each guess

Comment: until comopletion?

Comment: @JasonV Guess what exactly? They don't want to know each others numbers. They want to verify they are distinct.

Comment: usnt thatoart of the question? they know that each number is different?

Comment: I see whats being asked. my fault. I added a line to the pwuedo code

Comment: There is a lot of in depth discussion on Crypto SE [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25456/mutual-verification-of-shared-secret), and it seems to be a rather difficult problem, at least if you want to make sure that neither Alice nor Beth can cheat.

Comment: Is any outside equipment allowed? That is, a computer program, or a physical object of some sort? If so, this seems too broad; if not, you should clarify that in your question.

Comment: And more generally, *what techniques are allowed?* Should this be thought of in the abstract cryptographic sense, like "Alice and Beth can send each other messages, but that's all"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any commutative hash function will do. 
Using RSA makes this relatively easy, I think.

So Alice and Beth both establish their secret primes,
and, in a twist, keep everything secret. 
$ % Make EA, EB, DA and DB look like functions; i.e., *not* italic:
\def\EA{\operatorname{EA}}
\def\EB{\operatorname{EB}}
\def\DA{\operatorname{DA}}
\def\DB{\operatorname{DB}}
$
Then they have:

1. *Privately* available $\EA(x)$ and $\EB(x)$, which encrypt, and
2. Privately available $\DA(x)$ and $\DB(x)$, which decrypt (not used).

So $f_1(f_2(x))=f_2(f_1(x))$,
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are any two of $\EA$, $\EB$, $\DA$ and $\DB$.

Now suppose Alice's number is $a$ and Beth's is $b$. 
Then Alice publishes $\EA(a)$
and Beth uses that to publish $\EB(\EA(a))$.

Similarly, Beth publishes $\EB(b)$
and Alice uses that to publish $\EA(\EB(b))$.

These two are equal if and only if $a=b$,
but no information leaks if they are different.

A simple hash that could be used is to pick a secret number $y$
and share a number $z$ (e.g., 1000000) and then work out $2^{a+y} \mod z$.

Comment: This works, at least if Alice and Beth trust each other to not lie.  
If there were an advantage to knowing that their numbers are the same while keeping the other in the dark about that fact, then all bets are off. Alice could publish EA(a) correctly, but lie when publishing EA(EB(b)) by giving a different result. Beth would think their numbers are different, but Alice could (assuming Beth did not also lie) still find out whether the numbers matched by checking the real value of EA(EB(b)). Of course, Beth would have an incentive to lie too, so the whole scheme then falls apart.

Comment: I have to point out that there is no Bob in this puzzle.

Comment: this sounds good, but I think it's overly complicated.  Each person need only rot13(unir n havdhr 1-1 znccvat sebz rnpu ahzore 0-10 gb n ahzore orgjrra 0-10.  Gura gurl funer gurve znccrq inyhr jvgu rnpu bgure naq gura znc rnpu bguref nafjre.  Vs gurl'er gur fnzr ahzore, gura gur ahzoref ner gur fnzr. )  In order to avoid reverse engineering, each person should change their mapping each time they play.

Comment: @SteveV Permutations generally do not commute, and you need commutativity for this method to work. I thought for a moment you could use bitwise XOR with a private key, but it really also needs to be a one-way function so that it cannot be undone, i.e. knowing one plaintext/encryption pair (e.g. EA(a) and EB(EA(a)) ) should not allow the decryption of another number (e.g. EB(b) ).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis ah yes.  the samples i tried in my head were rotational, and those work.  It still works pretty simply... just rot13 (rnpu crefba hfrf n znccvat ol nqqvat be fhogenpgvat n ahzore sebz 0 gb 10.  gura vg'f pbzzhgngvir naq jbexf.  Naq pna or punatrq jvgu rnpu gevny fb gung vg'f abg erirefr ratvarrenoyr (vs gung'f n jbeq))

Comment: oops. just realized my simple method will give information about how far away the other person's number is.  which makes me wonder if even the RSA method gives _some_ sort of information, also, convoluted as it may be.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, Beth doesn't live here anymore (suitably creepy deadpan)

Comment: @SteveV, I think the hash function I gave at the end is straightforward and can be calculated pretty cheaply. I don't think it gives anything else away though...

Comment: @DrXorile Is that hash function commutative?

Comment: Considering there are only 10 possible numbers, publishing the hash of your number would easily reveal your number via a simple brute force search of the ten possible inputs. Considering the input space is so small I do not believe there is anyway to test for equality with giving away your own number.

Comment: @Spoonless That is why even though RSA is used, the (normally public) encryption keys are kept private as well.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, yes. It's basically the same as RSA except without all the fancy maths to make it reversible! If $x$ and $y$ are the two secrets, then the answer will be $2^{x+y+a}$ either way

Comment: @DrXorile The functions you have are $f_y(a)=2^{y+a}$ and $f_x(a)=2^{x+a}$, and you claim that $f_y(f_x(a)) = 2^{x+y+a}$. However, I get $f_y(f_x(a)) = 2^{y+2^{x+a}}$.

Comment: Good point. So you need to go $2^xf_y(a)=2^{x+y+a}$ mod $z$ and $2^yf_x(b)=2^{x+y+b}$ mod $z$.

Comment: @DrXorile Unfortunately that hash is reversible. The parties reveal the numbers $2^{y+a}$, $2^{x+b}$, $2^{x+y+a}$, and $2^{x+y+b}$. By modular division they can find out the hashing factors $2^x$ and $2^y$, from which they can then find out $2^a$ and $2^b$. The discrete log problem is no problem here since there are only 10 possibilities for each of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Ah yes you are correct. Mmm. Will have to think about it. I'm not sure if RSA would work then since it's two different ones.

Comment: This won't work because there are 10 numbers to try. Crypto works because there are essentially unlimited numbers you would have to attempt before guessing the correct one.

Comment: @zizyarcher, this point has been covered in the answer and the discussion.

Comment: When Alice will tell Beth her EA(x) then Beth knows that x is 1 to 10 .  Beth can check what EA(1) , EA(2) , EA(3)...EA(10) is . Let's say that Beth notices that EA(4) = EA(x) . Then won't Beth know that Alice has the number 4? Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 12):

> There are 10 rooms labelled 1-10. Put Alice in her room, and ask Beth to go through the door with her number on it. When this is done, turn the lights back on - if the two girls are in the same room, they have the same number. If not, they don't, and no-one is any the wiser other than that.

Comment: This seems along the lines of 'third party'--as coordinating this becomes difficult with just Alice and Beth, and as the number of rooms becomes large.

Comment: @nahmid not really, they can coordinate everything by themselves (thinking cell phones here), so the room numbers act like a hash function that only reveals information when both secrets are equal.

Comment: I can't tell if the question specify Alice and Beth are not supposed to reveal their number in case they are the same?  If not this is a good way to test

Comment: @Alex if the rooms were organised in a circle, and the numbers were not on the doors - but the 3rd party "knew" where door 1, door 2, was etc, they girls would be none the wiser even if they were in the same room.

Comment: @Moo-Juice If Alice knows her own number and she knows that Beth has the same number, she will always know the number Beth has, because it is the same as her own. So any algorithm will indirectly reveal the other ones number, if they have the same number - by logical deduction.

Answer (score 8):

Alice takes 1 cardboard box, 10 envelopes, 9 matching coins or disk, and 1 coin/disk of the same size/shape/weight, with a different colour or pattern.  This difference may be disclosed in advance - see the final step.

Alice places 1 coin in each of the envelopes and seals them all (keeping track of the "different" coin) then stacks the envelopes inside the cardboard box, with the "different" coin at the position indicated by her number - i.e. on top for `1`, at the bottom for `10`, and so on.  The cardboard box is used to prevent Beth from being able to observe the order that Alice stacks the envelopes in.

Beth and Alice then swap places.  Beth retrieves the envelope that matches **her** number from the stack - the cardboard box again preventing Alice from observing which envelope is taken.  The box is shaken vigorously to scramble the untaken envelopes, and returned to Alice.

Under observation of both, either Beth's envelope (if the difference is known) or **all** envelopes (in a random order) are opened.  If Beth's coin is not the odd one out, they have different numbers.

(While Alice *could* mark the envelopes to learn about Beth's number, Beth can see the envelopes to certify that this has not happened.  Similarly, Beth *could* open additional envelopes to find Alice's number - but Alice can certify whether or not the returned envelopes have been tampered with)

Comment: Nicely done! I wasn't able to visualize how this process might work, but it's good that you could :)

Comment: @Avi Essentially, I tried to deduce a method by which Alice could indicate True / False, for all 10 numbers, which would destroy the other 9 options when Beth selected any of them, while *also* preventing Alice from knowing which item was taken.

Comment: (1) Upvoted because this takes the concept of [JMP’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/90586/19765#90589) and makes it logistically practical and somewhat scalable (although it may be impractical for $N$ greater than, say, $100$).  (2) I don’t see why you need coins or disks.  ISTM that all you need is $N-1$ blank pieces of paper and one piece of paper that says “yes”.  It might be possible for Alice to cheat by making the blank sheets non-identical.  Allowing Beth to produce (and/or inspect) the $N$ pieces of paper may suffice as a countermeasure. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) ... (3) I don’t see why you need the box — just have the participants turn their back when they are handling the envelopes.

Comment: @PeregrineRook While the primary purpose of the box is to preserve anonymity (in **both** directions — Alice can't see which envelope Beth takes, but she can tell if Beth starts opening or messing with *multiple* envelopes), its *secondary* purpose is to be shaken after Beth's selection, to scramble/randomise the unselected envelopes and destroy the information about Alice's number in the scenario that they are different.  Turning backs is “Trust…”; adding the box is “… but verify.”

Answer (score 3):

Alice takes a basic calculator (a simple one that doesn't show history) and covers up the screen with something (paper, non-transparent tape, etc). Alice types in her number and hits the divide key. Beth takes the calculator, types in her number and hits the equals key. They take the cover off the screen and if the screen shows any number other than 1, they have different numbers.

Comment: I like this, but they are supposed to *reveal no information about their individual numbers*. If the calculator shows anything else than 1 it could very well reveal their numbers.

Comment: @Wolff With a trick we can get this to work?  While reading the answer from the calculator, first cover it with a paper and slowly move the paper downward, to a point you see some pixels.  You will be able to see if the answer has more than 1 digit.  Secondly, while still covering the answer, only read the first rightmost digit.  From these you can tell if the answer is not a '1' but unable to tell the answer.  Much like when you play cards from casino.  I mean this might not be an algorithm but kinda works

Comment: @Alex, there might be a trick. But if Alice has 1 and Beth has 10 the calculator could show 0.1 so you'll have to move the paper until you see the period and then they both know what the other had.

Comment: Most calculator have a "ans" key. So instead of a division, use a soustraction. then type "ans/ans". So if the numbers are the same it will show "ERROR" and if they are differents, it will show 1. This also work with calculators that show the calcul.

Comment: @Wolff Not just "could", but "will".  Alice just divides her number by the result, and Beth multiplies her number by the result.

Comment: @GAB even without an ans key, they could just type blind: zero divded by ( a - b ) and look at the result. If it shows 0 they had different number, if it shows ERROR they had the same

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a modification of @JMP's answer:

> Alice and Beth write a following Python script (or an equivalent in other language) and run it on a computer:
>
> ```
>  # getpass prompts the user to enter a string (a password) without echoing
>  from getpass import getpass
>  a = getpass("Alice: ")
>  b = getpass("Beth: ")
>  try:
>      print(int(a) != int(b))  # prints True if their numbers are different, False otherwise
>  except:
>      # to avoid echoing in case of something mistyped, e.g. '8a' instead of '8'
>      print("Non-number string entered")
> ```
>
> Then Alice inputs her numbers, and then Beth inputs her one (of course, they do it while the other girl does not see the keyboard). By the output, they both can see the result (even not having to reveal their numbers to each other when they are the same (comment by @Alex to @JMP's answer) - but this requirement seems useless, since they obviously would know the numbers of each other if they know that the numbers are the same).

The advantage of this answer over JMP's one is

> that this solution works with any range of possible numbers (e.g. if it would be 1 to 1 000 000 000, it's difficult to even build a billion rooms (and much more difficult is not to get lost inside them)).

Comment: If Beth is a clever hacker, she can find the value of `a` in the program's memory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Alice and Beth can be assigned the same number, then no such algorithm exists, since the algorithm would sometimes reveal that the numbers are not distinct, which means revealing their numbers to each other.

(If Alice and Beth cannot be assigned the same number, then that needs to be specified)

Comment: From the question "but ensure that they reveal no information about their individual numbers (apart from the fact that they are different!)." - so the information different/same may be revealed (this is the goal of the algorithm) but nothing else. - So if they have the same number, the information can be revealed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use truncating division, either $\frac{a}{b}$ or $\frac{b}{a}$ will be $0$, provided that $a\neq{}b$. Therefore, let Alice and Beth hand over their numbers to a trusted black box (which will never reveal their information), that will simply return to Alice and Beth the value $\frac{a}{b}\cdot{}\frac{b}{a}$. If the values are the same, this will return $1$, otherwise $0$. Establishing a trusted black box is the hard part here.

Comment: You can't use a third party, otherwise the problem becomes trivial. Just have A and B tell their numbers to the third party individually and let the third party tell them whether they are different or not...

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Good point. Looks like this won't work, then :(

Comment: @avi See my answer, in which the "trusted black box" is literally a cardboard box, used to transmit only the information of "same" or "different"

Answer (score 0):

Basing this off rfajardo's answer,

Write a computer program that takes 2 input parameters one after another (performs clear screen after each input given) and then returns a boolean true or false depending on the result of the (a==b) operation.

An additional buffer flush can be performed once the result is displayed, to prevent either person from reading the given inputs (assuming they are adept enough to retrieve data from the buffer).

Sure, the computer acts as a 3rd party here but it cannot disclose information if you close out loopholes.

If the result of (a==b) is True, the numbers match. If the result is False, they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Open 2 minecraft clients. In the seed section of the map input Alice's and Berth's numbers.

If the maps have the same structure then they have the same number.

Comment: Problem:  After doing this, Alice can open another minecraft client, and try entering keys until she finds one with the same structure as the one from Beth's key.

Comment: Right, but then any algorithm with endless time can be broken right? Also I think this same answer can be applied to the polarisation algorithm I read below

Answer (score 0):

Both define a conversion from their numbers to a rotation of a polarisation filter.

Then they adjust a polarisation filter to that rotation, so that if their numbers are equal, the direction of polarisation of both filters is the same.

Now Alice sends a string of random 0/1 as polarised light (single quantums). When sending a 1 the polarised light has to be aligned with her filter, when sending a 0 it has to be orthogonal.
Only if Bobs filter is aligned exactly as Alices, he will receive the exact same string when looking through his filter, seeing 1 as light on and 0 as light off. If it is misaligned, he will receive a randomized string.
Now Bob sends a shifted sequence of the same string.
If Alice receives, what she sent, their numbers are equal.
Now they can repeat the same into the other direction, so Bob knows the result, too.

This is based on some methods of post quantum key exchange I've read about and should guarantee, that no Information leaks and it is at least close to "just sending messages" and doesn't require a 3rd party.

Comment: Wouldn't a misaligned filter result in results which correlate imperfectly to the original data, not independently random results? So if Alice sees that 80% of the bits returned match what she sent, she can calculate the approximate angle between the two polarizers.

Comment: @aschepler Yes, you are right - hashing the message should fix it though.

Comment: Hashing at what point? I'm not seeing how that could prevent a calculation of angle.

Comment: @aschepler the returning message. Alice sends 10011001 - Bob receives 10111001, now he hashes that and sends back the hash. Alice can compare the hash result of her sent message with what Bob got out of it. If it is a mismatch, she wouldn't know, how much of difference there is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @rfajardo and the comment by @Falco:

1. Take a calculator and cover the screen
2. Alice enters her number and hits `-`
3. Beth enters her number and hits `=` and `1/x`
4. Alice hits `/` or `*` followed by any  number except `0` and then `=` , making sure that Beth does not see the input
5. Beth does the same, without Alice seeing it
6. Uncover the screen

If the screen shows `Error` (on my mobile phone) or `0` (on my RPN calculator), the numbers were equal.
Any other result means that the numbers were different, but they can not tell which numbers it were.

Comment: Even easier by just entering 0 / ( a - b )

Comment: @Falco that is right

Answer (score 0):

Request to show up at a designated place at the time of your number. Leave at 5 minutes past your number's time and only arrive within 5 minutes before. If they both show up, they have the same number. This assumes both parties are in good faith but all of the algorithms inherently assume that as well. (This is clearly not the most time efficient way, but it was fun to imagine)